# What is the Better way Django Tags with DRF

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, orm, django-taggit

I'm developing a Blog project with Django. I have thoughts on 'tag'. What should be the best approach? What I want is a tag system like here(stackoverflow)

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    title =
    subtitle =
    category = FK
    author = FK
    content =
    tags = ManyToMany
    
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = 
    slug =
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you've got there?